# Adding a Registration Form to the featured articles list in Joomla 3.7

Tags: joomla

I am building a site in Joomla 3.7 which uses the 'featured articles' menu type to display the home page content. The site has user registration enabled too with a registration page elsewhere on the site.

Is it possible to integrate the Joomla! user registration form into the bottom of my home page?

Comment: Do you use a third party plugin for user registration?

Comment: No I'm using a fresh install of Joomla3.7 with no 3rd party plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Components Anywhere by RegularLabs to load more than one component per page: https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/componentsanywhere

I am a big fan of their extensions because they make some advanced tasks super easy.